# Magento 2: What is difference between Cache Clean & Cache Flush?

Tags: magento2, cache, command-line

In Magento 2 we have 2 commands

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

What's the exact difference between them? I'm generally using `cache:flush`. I never used `cache:clean`. So, when to use which command & in which situation?

Comment: Please read [Magento 2 Cache Overview And Solution](https://www.mageants.com/blog/magento-2-cache-overview-and-solution.html) with this post helpful to understand difference between Cache Clean & Cache Flush

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To purge out-of-date items from the cache, you can *clean* or *flush* cache types:

- Cleaning a cache type deletes all items from enabled Magento cache
  types only. In other words, this option does not affect other
  processes or applications because it cleans only the cache that
  Magento uses.

  Disabled cache types are not cleaned.
- Flushing a cache type purges the cache storage, which might affect
  other processes applications that are using the same storage.

Flush cache types if you’ve already tried cleaning the cache and you’re still having issues that you cannot isolate.

***Source:*** https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cache.html#config-cli-subcommands-cache-clean

Comment: Can I know which are the other processes applications which will use Magento cache storage.

Comment: You can enable performance in Magento by configuring Configuring Redis for backend cache,Configuring Memcached for session caching and Configuring Varnish as a Full Page Cache (This is explained in detail in Magento 2 Cook Book by Ray Bogman). The other applications in sense if you have a single Redis or any other server running and configured with more than one Magento or any other applications. Running Flush will delete all directory + files but running clean will delete files alone in \Magento\var\cache dir.

Comment: @BalaVaradarajan I'm afraid I don't get it. Does anyone do that? I wouldn't come up with the idea to share a cache with different applications or Magento instances. Sounds very special.

Answer (score 14):

**php bin/magento cache:clean**

Cleaning a cache type deletes all items from enabled Magento cache types only. In other words, this option does not affect other processes or applications because it cleans only the cache that Magento uses.

> Disabled cache types are not cleaned.

**php bin/magento cache:flush**

Flushing a cache type purges the cache storage, which might affect other processes applications that are using the same storage.

Reference: [DevDocs Manage the cache](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cache.html)

Comment: Thanks @Rafael. So which is best & when to use?

Comment: Depends, but I prefer cache:clear

Comment: I've tried to create an empty file on var/cache and it was not deleted by any of these commands as you mentioned. But thanks for that anyway.

Comment: @RicardoMartins it is because you need to create a file like var/cache/mage--test-martines

Comment: This answer is the opposite of the chosen answer If I am correct

Comment: I think this answer is wrong as what Magento says in Doc https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cache.html.  Why there are upvotes?

Answer (score 4):

Quoting [Fabrizio Branca](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun/issues/588#issuecomment-112453280) for this one:

> (...) Magento that
>   comes with those two different actions in the first place (you'll also
>   find two buttons on the cache management page).
>
> While cache:clean deletes the cache storage by tags cache:flush will
>   wipe out everything.
>
> There are two major differences here:
>
> - some things are stored into the cache without the proper tags. cache:clean will not delete those.
> - other things might be using the same cache storage (this is not recommended, but sadly sometimes this is the case). Flushing the cache
>     will result in everything being deleted. So if multiple Magento
>     instances use the same cache storage or if you store your sessions in
>     the same Redis database you're using for the cache (please don't! :)
>     then they will also be gone.

Other resources:

- [Technical explanation and details (From Magenteiro) (In Portuguese)](https://www.magenteiro.com/blog/magento-2/cache_clean-ou-cache_flush-diferencas/)
- [Cache management (official docs)](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/cache-management.html)
- [About the 10 cache types in Magento (from Mageplaza's blog)](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/10-cache-types-how-manage-cache-magento-2.html)

Answer (score 1):

**php bin/magento cache:clean**

> Cleaning a cache type deletes all items from enabled Magento cache
>   types only. In other words, this option does not affect other
>   processes or applications because it cleans only the cache that
>   Magento uses.
>
> Disabled cache types are not cleaned.

**php bin/magento cache:flush**

> Flushing a cache type purges the cache storage, which might affect
>   other processes applications that are using the same storage.

Answer (score 0):

Using `bin/magento cache:clean` you can specify(comma-separated) cache types you want to clean.

Supported types:

```
config, layout, block_html, collections, reflection, db_ddl, eav,
customer_notification, target_rule, full_page, config_integration,
config_integration_api, translate, config_webservice
```

Comment: You can do that with cache:flush as well. See https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cache.html.

Answer (score 0):

While `cache:clean` deletes the cache storage by tags `cache:flush` will wipe out everything.

There are two major differences here:

some things are stored into the cache without the proper tags. cache:clean will not delete those.
other things might be using the same cache storage (this is not recommended, but sadly sometimes this is the case). Flushing the cache will result in everything being deleted. So if multiple Magento instances use the same cache storage or if you store your sessions in the same redis database you're using for the cache (please don't! :) then they will also be gone.

Source : https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun/issues/588#issuecomment-112453280